# How can I test a Vue component which watches a ref prop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3

I am trying to test the following Vue component. Once the loading state is updated from true to false it should show the success icon for 3 seconds. I'm trying to write a component test for this and it doesn't seem like it's possible to test this using either the Vue Testing Library or Vue test utils for several reasons (mount/render doesn't accept props, watchers don't behave the same way in tests, etc...). At this point i'm considering changing my approach and making a composable to test instead of trying to test the component directly, although I think I might run into the same problems seen here. Any ideas?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  loading?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  error?: boolean;
  loadingSuccessText?: string;
  loadingSuccessIcon?: string;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  loading: false,
  label: "button",
  error: false,
  loadingSuccessText: "Success",
  loadingSuccessIcon: "circle-check",
});

const loadingTimeoutId = ref<number | undefined>(undefined);
const clicking = ref(false);
const loading = toRef(props, "loading");

const loadingFinished = computed(() => !!loadingTimeoutId.value);

watch(loading, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if (newVal != oldVal && !newVal) return;
  clearTimeout(loadingTimeoutId.value);
  loadingTimeoutId.value = setTimeout(() => {
    loadingTimeoutId.value = undefined;
  }, 3000);
});
</script>

<template>
  <button
    id="button"
    :aria-label="label"
    :class="['gradient-button', clicking ? 'gradient-button--clicked' : '']"
    @mousedown="clicking = true"
    @mouseup="clicking = false"
    @mouseleave="clicking = false"
  >
    <span v-if="loadingFinished && !loading && !error">
      {{ loadingSuccessText }}
      <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="loadingSuccessIcon" data-testid="success" />
    </span>
    <slot v-else-if="!loading"></slot>
    <span v-else class="loader loader--small" data-testid="spinner"></span>
  </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test code like this:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import YourComponent from '@/path/to/YourComponent.vue';

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  it('test prop changes', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(YourComponent, {
      props: {
          loading: true,
      },
    });

    await wrapper.setProps({ loading: false });
    expect(wrapper.vm.loadingTimeoutId).toBeDefined();
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    expect(wrapper.vm.loadingTimeoutId).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Or you can encapsulate the code into a function and test that function.It will be easier to test and more composable:

```
// loading.ts
export default (props: any) => {
  const loading = toRef(props, "loading");
  const loadingTimeoutId = ref<number | undefined>(undefined);
  watch(loading, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    if (newVal != oldVal && !newVal) return;
    clearTimeout(loadingTimeoutId.value);
    loadingTimeoutId.value = setTimeout(() => {
      loadingTimeoutId.value = undefined;
    }, 3000);
  });
  return {
    loading,
    loadingTimeoutId
  }
}
```